# Is the Collatz conjecture known to be true for interesting unbounded classes of numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, open-problems, integer-sequences, collatz-conjecture

The Collatz or the $3n+1$ conjecture is open.

1. Is there a specific polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ whose range is unbounded for which every integer of form $|f(m)|$ at $m\in\mathbb Z$ satisfies $3n+1$ conjecture?
2. What about the case of numbers of form $3^x$ (simplest *non-trivial* non-polynomial) where $x\in\mathbb Z$. Do these satisfy Collatz conjecture?

Comment: I suppose you're not interested in such trivial answers as $3\times2^n$, $5\times2^n$, and suchlike (but I feel compelled to mention them, just in case).

Comment: No I am not interested.

Comment: I think question 1 might be more natural without the absolute value. Or restricted to polynomials $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Related question from OP: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412416/polynomials-3x-and-the-collatz-conjecture

Comment: There are of course many unbounded non-trivial non-polynomials for which every integer satisfies the conjecture, such as all nets of the form $\langle2\rangle\cdot\{4^n\cdot x+\frac{4^n-1}3:n\in\Bbb N\}$ where $x$ is any 5-rough number known to satisfy the conjecture.

Comment: The Collatz conjecture is known to be true for specific numbers. 1,2, and 3 are examples. I know that is not what is intended, I am just suggesting a more specific title might be appropriate.

Comment: About Collatz starting at $3^n$, see https://oeis.org/A070976